# Polymer tests never end on windows machines

Tags: windows, testing, polymer, polymer-1.0, wct

I've developed an application using Polymer 1.0. My developer computer is a Mac, and I've not had any problems during development process.

However, when I clone my application on a Windows machine (Windows 10), the tests don't work at all.

Whenever I execute `polymer test` or `wct` the command blocks the terminal and never ends.

On MACOS or Linux it works perfectly.

Comment: WCT indeed starts slow on my machine too. Did you try `--verbose` maybe it will reveal some additional detail. Also, `--skip-selenium-install` should save you some seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround.

It seems that there is a bug in Web Component Tester. When it tries to find all the browsers installed on a windows machine it takes ages to locate some of them.

To solve this problem, just adds an environment variable that tells WCT which browsers are installed, so it can skip this step:

```
LAUNCHPAD_BROWSERS= _{coma delimited list of browsers}_
```

For instance:

```
LAUNCHPAD_BROWSERS=chrome,firefox,opera
```

Once this variable has been set, all the tests execute just like on any other OS.

More information about this feature [here](https://github.com/daffl/launchpad#environment-variables-impacting-local-browsers-detection)

Answer (score 1):

The following environment variable values have saved me in Win10 environment:

```
LAUNCHPAD_BROWSERS=chrome

LAUNCHPAD_CHROME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

It is not obvious from Polymer and [launchpad](https://github.com/bitovi/launchpad#environment-variables-impacting-local-browsers-detection) documentation the need to set **only single browser** with known location to minimize the test run time during ongoing development. Of course for multiple browsers autodetection it will take more time and traverse over all PATH with guess on all possible browsers takes forever. It would be reasonable not to rely on auto-detection and list in LAUNCHPAD_BROWSERS **only browsers you have set** in LAUNCHPAD_xxx location.